# Mac OS: How to revert settings that have been changed by a certain program

Tags: macos, mac, display, graphics, settings

**Short Story**

I've installed a program on my Mac that altered some settings (e.g. graphics, position of dock). I've uninstalled the program but the settings haven't changed. Is there a way that I can see the setting that were changed by this program and revert them?

**Long Story**

I've recently purchased a [Matrox Dualhead2go Digital ME](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/dh2go/digital_me/?utm_campaign=DH2Go_ME_PR&utm_medium=PR&utm_source=PR) this device allows the user to connect two external displays to their existing MacBooks. Once I unboxed it I successfully connected two external displays and I was able to use it properly. I was able to control the display settings from System Preferences -> Displays.

I then installed the software that supposedly 'gives more options to the user'. However, the software did not even detect that the device was connected. Moreover, it seems like it has altered the settings in some way. What I have noticed so far:

- The internal display started to blink occasionally from time to time for no reason at all.
- The dock is now moved slightly to the left
- My Mac can no longer detect the two external displays (and therefore the device is now useless)

These are all annoying changes and I would like to change all three; individually or together by reverting the settings to the state before the program was installed. Is there a way to do this?

I am using a MacBook Air with OS X Mavericks 10.9.4

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2619229 Some plist files would have to be deleted.